# Can't get updated location using custom class

Tags: swift, core-location, clgeocoder

I create a custom LocationManager so I can just use that object to get the location of the user anywhere in the app, but It seems like I can't get the location using the object that I created, here's my `LocationManager.swift` file

```swift
import CoreLocation

class LocationManager: NSObject {
    private var locationManager: CLLocationManager?
    private var locationCallback: ((CLLocation?, String?) -> Void)?
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
        print("initlocmen")
        self.locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        self.locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        self.locationManager?.delegate = self
    }
    
    func requestLocationAndCity(callback: @escaping (CLLocation?, String?) -> Void) {
        self.locationCallback = callback
        
        guard let locationManager = locationManager else {
            return
        }
        
        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            let status = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
            
            if status == .authorizedAlways || status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
//                locationManager.requestLocation()
                print("Location allowed")
                locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            } else if status == .notDetermined {
                locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            } else if status == .denied || status == .restricted {
                callback(nil, nil)
            } else {
                callback(nil, nil)
            }
        } else {
            callback(nil, nil)
        }
    }
}

extension LocationManager: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        locationManager?.stopUpdatingLocation()
        print("didUpdateLocations")
        if let location = locations.last {
            // Reverse geocode the location to get the city
            CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { [weak self] placemarks, error in
                if let city = placemarks?.first?.locality {
                    self?.locationCallback?(location, city)
                } else {
                    self?.locationCallback?(location, nil)
                }
            }
        } else {
            locationCallback?(nil, nil)
        }
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("Error getting location:", error)
        locationCallback?(nil, nil)
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .authorizedWhenInUse || status == .authorizedAlways {
            locationManager?.requestLocation()
        } else {
            locationCallback?(nil, nil)
        }
    }
}
```

I use it in my view controller like this

```swift
let locationManager = LocationManager()
locationManager.requestLocationAndCity { location, city in
    print("user city", city ?? "none")
}
```

I only see the logs `Location allowed` because I already allowed my device to access the location services, but it seems like I can't get on didUpdateLocations,

I already tried to change the `locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()` into `locationManager.requestLocation()` but nothing happened.

What's wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Comment: Did you add anything to the plist file?

Comment: I guess you throw away the local variable `locationManager` before the data are received. Use a strong reference or turn the manager into an `actor`. By the way in times of the `Result` type returning tuples are out and in times of `async/await` completion handlers are out.

Comment: @son yes, I already make it work before on my other view controller, I just want it to globalize so I'm trying to create a custom class in it

Comment: @vadian can you identify which part of my code where I accidentally throw away my `locationManager`? I tried to log my `locationManager.delegate` under my `Location allowed` print and I get a value like this `Optional(<PNB_Digital.LocationManager: 0x281e447e0>)`

Comment: I mean the line `let locationManager = LocationManager()`. It's a local variable. At the moment you exit the enclosing scope the object will be deallocated.

Comment: @vadian yes, I initialize it In my view controller like this `let locationManager = LocationManager()` then I call the `requestLocationAndCity` in it, did I do something wrong in it?

Comment: You don't understand, `requestLocationAndCity` works asynchronously. Likely the object has been destroyed before it can return anything.

Comment: @vadian ohh, I see, I get it, thank you, I add this on my object `static let ready = LocationManager()` then I call it on my controller like this `LocationManager.ready.requestLocationAndCity` and it works, you can answer that and I accept it as right answer, but you can also explain it on your answer how it works., thanks

Comment: No, better add `var locationManager : LocationManager?` at the **top level** of the controller, assign the instance to that property and reset it to `nil` after having received the data. Or - still better – use Swift Concurrency like an actor. It handles the life cycle on your behalf.

Comment: but I'm just always using it on a single enlosing block, I think adding it on top level of every controller that I use it make it more work? or I can add a `deinit` on `LocationManager` to remove the instance of objects inside it, will it work?

Comment: You cannot call `deinit`. As I said use an `actor`.